# Hosting Javascript/Css on CDN fails to load on slow connections

Tags: javascript, html, css, cdn, google-cdn

I am using various other Javascripts/Css to load from Google hosted libraries but they fail to load on slow connections. Please guide me to find an alternative solution for the same.

I tried searching for the solution most of them say download the js/css files and include in your project and run, this is not the solution.

Please help to find the solution for the slow connections.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Usually javascript or css on CDN loads faster if you use libraries hosted by Google etc. So the alternative you tried is to attach the file/s in your project.According to you that's too is slow.So you have only one option left.That's to copy the codes from the libraries and paste it directly into your HTML page.
Point to remember that, whatever way you try, ultimately your script or css need to be downloaded by the browser in order to use them. So,ultimately all ways are some.But servers like Google is are always faster than most of the other servers we used.So in real time scenario CDN is a little bit faster.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But then scripts fails to load via CDN. Pasting the codes in the html file is kind of risky. Could you help for the solution with slow connections. Facing the problem very now and then.

Comment: "Pasting the codes in the html file is kind of risky"!!I totally disagree.Because whatever you try, you can't hide your css or javascript from the user.Because it needs to be downloaded in order to view.So you can paste the code in the html.

Comment: what about to load the content from jquery like websites. Jquery to doesn't load on slow internet connection.

Comment: I couldn't get what you say.Please elaborate

Comment: Please if you can click on the [image](http://lh6.ggpht.com/gkNY6owW8pj9_PISg2jlznVo60A3BSh6oAMfj-jykgEy2s6cS3AM_ObEI1WoyKcfn5LejTIUsqi-SGsVn3CKi7A46lE) and see the errors which are coming due to slow connection. Jquery fails to load on slow connections.

Comment: According to your screenshot it seems like the problem is not with your connection.The problem is with your code.Check the code throughly(may be the script source file is modified by mistake)

Comment: Slow connection is the issue. Every thing is working well on faster laptop with broadband. But then mobile or laptop with internet connection on data card fails to load. Test it thoroughly and then pasting the issue here.